# How to give more RAM to wine Applications

Tags: 12.04, wine, ram

Hi I think my system is not allocating enough RAM to WINE applications . I am using WINE to play games but they are loading slowly and RAM usage is normal. So how can I improve reserve memory of WINE?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**RAM**:
I don't think there is much you can do as wine takes what it needs. As it is 32bit the upper limit is 4Gb. Then there is a 2Gb (sometimes 3Gb) limit for RAM per application.

**Video RAM (VRAM)**:
You can allow more VRAM by editing the wine registy:

1. `wine regedit`
2. go to:
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER → Software → Wine → Direct3D → VideoMemorySize
   and set the value to a higher one. The default seems to be 64Mb.
   If you see no such key, create it (right-click on *Direct3D*, select *New* then *String Value* and name it VideoMemorySize).

More registry information:  [useful registry keys](http://wiki.winehq.org/UsefulRegistryKeys) from wiki.winehq.org.

This [detailed memory management](http://www.winehq.org/docs/winedev-guide/x2800) page from the wine developer notes might give more clues but it is quite technical.

Comment: but i am not having that option.

Comment: Try adding the Direct3D folder, then create the key. Then close all wine applications so the wine server does not run.
What wine version are you running? (wine --version)

Comment: Did adding the folder work?

Comment: amigo I'm in home on vacation . doing this from mobile . I'll try and let you know .

Comment: Is this still accurate?