# Wine program crashes when clicking its window: "System.OutOfMemoryException"

Tags: 14.04, wine, crash

I successfully installed [this program](http://www.ujp.gov.mk/e/obrasci/pogledni/127) on wine and it launches fine, but when I click anywhere on it, the program closes without giving any error.

I'm using Wine 1.7.55 on Ubuntu 14.04

**Edited:**

This is the output when I open it in terminal:

```
fixme:wincodecs:JpegDecoder_Frame_CopyPalette (0x184c34,0x14e550): stub
fixme:wincodecs:JpegDecoder_Frame_CopyPalette (0x1aad64,0x185318): stub
fixme:wincodecs:JpegDecoder_Frame_CopyPalette (0xb36d0ec,0xb336ea0): stub
fixme:wincodecs:JpegDecoder_Frame_CopyPalette (0xb3d4dac,0xb3d4cb0): stub
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
err:dc:CreateDCW no device found for L""
err:winspool:DocumentPropertiesA no name from hPrinter?
err:dc:CreateDCW no device found for L""
err:winspool:DocumentPropertiesA no name from hPrinter?
err:dc:CreateDCW no device found for L""
err:winspool:DocumentPropertiesA no name from hPrinter?
fixme:gdiplus:GdipGetLineSpacing ignoring style
fixme:gdiplus:GdipGetLineSpacing ignoring style
fixme:gdiplus:GdipGetLineSpacing ignoring style
fixme:gdiplus:GdipGetLineSpacing ignoring style
fixme:gdiplus:GdipGetLineSpacing ignoring style
fixme:gdiplus:GdipGetLineSpacing ignoring style
fixme:gdiplus:GdipGetLineSpacing ignoring style
fixme:gdiplus:GdipGetLineSpacing ignoring style
fixme:gdiplus:GdipGetLineSpacing ignoring style
fixme:gdiplus:GdipGetLineSpacing ignoring style
fixme:gdiplus:GdipGetLineSpacing ignoring style
fixme:gdiplus:GdipGetLineSpacing ignoring style
fixme:gdiplus:GdipGetLineSpacing ignoring style
fixme:gdiplus:GdipGetLineSpacing ignoring style
```

And this is the output after I click on the program and it crashes:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Not enough memory to complete operation [GDI+ status: OutOfMemory]
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus (Status status) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd (IntPtr hwnd) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIWin32.GetAutoScaleSize (System.Drawing.Font font) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI.GetAutoScaleSize (System.Drawing.Font font) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.GetAutoScaleSize (System.Drawing.Font font) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ApplyAutoScaling () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoadInternal (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore (Boolean value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore (Boolean value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible (Boolean value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Control:set_Visible (bool)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunLoop (Boolean Modal, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog (IWin32Window owner) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Form:ShowDialog (System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window)
  at System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog.ShowDialog (IWin32Window owner) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog.ShowDialog () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog:ShowDialog ()
  at WindowsApplication1.Form1.Vcituvanje_od_fajl () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at WindowsApplication1.Form1.vcitajBtn_Click (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.OnMouseUp (System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs mevent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp (System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs mevent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmLButtonUp (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlWindowTarget.OnMessage (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc (IntPtr hWnd, Msg msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Is there any output when you launch it from the terminal as `wine /PATH/TO/EXECUTABLE_FILE.EXE`? If so, please [edit] your question and add it. Thanks.

Comment: @ByteCommander I edited the question as you said ... any idea!?

Comment: The crash output says it's an `OutOfMemoryException` - could you monitor your RAM and SWAP usage while trying to run the program?

Comment: @ByteCommander I did the monitoring, RAM never exceeds 50% and SWAP didn't even go avove 0.8%. By the way, this program is very simple and only 2MB, I don't think it needs to much memory. Maybe Wine is not configured as should. Is there any tweak ...

Comment: Please see http://askubuntu.com/q/203645/367990, but it's not too informative. Maybe you should follow and read the links in the answer...?